# How to create a balance script based on the cursor position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something very similar to this game. http://i301.photobucket.com/albums/nn42/playonlineflashgame/HomeRun.swf

Although it's not a game, it's just a simple "balance" thing i'm trying to apply according to the movement of the cursor.

Same idea as the link i've provided up there where the guy starting swaying left and right according to where your cursor is. The think is that I've struggling to get the same smoothness like the effect you see in the game. Acceleration, innertia, gravity etc... not sure if it needs to be that complicated but the simpler the better.

So if anyone ever built or done anything like that who can help me out, I would appreciate for life?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea of what I would do for this problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3UaA/

Comment: Thanks Adam, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter. I was going to say that. I'm trying something like this. (for some reason doesnt work on jsdiffle properly). Just need to smooth it out. http://jsfiddle.net/DNKE4/